# PasteSpecial of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, paste

I am trying to select copy everything from a "database" workbook. and paste it in the current workbook, sheet 5. The code I am using is the following.

```
Sub Import()

Dim DBaseWB As Workbook
Set DBaseWB = Workbooks.Open("http://collaboration.pwc.ca/team/Plant5EngineLines/Documents/Plant 5 master build plan/Database.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False)
' set DBaseWB as the database workbook after opening it from sharepoint.

Dim DBaseSheet As Worksheet
Set DBaseSheet = DBaseWB.Sheets(1)        'DBaseSheet is referenced to sheet 1 of Database workbook.

Sheet5.Cells.Clear
DBaseSheet.UsedRange.Copy                               'Copy everything from the database
Sheet5.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll              'Paste everything in sheet 5 of current workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
DBaseWB.Close saveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I am receiving an error when running the following code. Though, sometimes it doesn't give me an error.

> Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

I think I know why it's giving me an error at the PasteSpecial line. When I have a different cell selected in sheet 5, it gives me no error. but when I recheck, without selecting any other cell, (so it will have the pasted range selected), I get this error.

I tried using the following line between copy and pastespecial,

```
Sheet5.range("A1").select
```

it gives me the same error.

**----------UPDATE----------**

I first used DisplayName's solution and it worked until yesterday. But this morning, it was causing problems. It another error. Then I tried all other solutions with no luck. all gave me the same errors. I also added the workbook.worksheet to the solutions below giving me no luck. This time the error was with the copy method. I also noticed that lots of columns say #REF.

Versions I tried:

DisplayName's solution combined with thisworkbook.worksheet

```
Sheet5.UsedRange.Clear
With Workbooks.Open("http://collaboration.pwc.ca/team/Plant5EngineLines/Documents/Plant 5 master build plan/Database.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False) 'open and reference your Database workbook
    .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Range("A1") ' copy referenced workbook sheet 1 content and paste it to sheet 5
    .Close False
End With
```

Gary's Student's solution combined with thisworkbook.worksheet

```
Dim DBaseWB As Workbook
Set DBaseWB = Workbooks.Open("http://collaboration.pwc.ca/team/Plant5EngineLines/Documents/Plant 5 master build plan/Database.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False)
' set DBaseWB as the database workbook after opening it from sharepoint.

Dim DBaseSheet As Worksheet
Set DBaseSheet = DBaseWB.Sheets(1)        'DBaseSheet is referenced to sheet 1 of Database workbook.

Dim Destination As Worksheet
Set DestinSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5)

Sheet5.Cells.Clear
DBaseSheet.UsedRange.Copy DestinSh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial     'copy database info in planning tool.

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
DBaseWB.Close saveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

errors:

> Run-time error '1004': Copy method of Range class failed

Comment: What workbook is `Sheet5` on?  When you open `DBaseWB`, as you have your code, I believe `Sheet5.Cells.Clear` will clear the "Sheet5" sheet on `DBaseWB`.

Comment: Since "Sheet5" is in the workbook with the macro, you should declare ThisWorkbook as a variable. By doing that, you will not run into the issue when you copy and then paste into the workbook you just opened.

Comment: oh makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First insure that there are **no merged cells** on either worksheet, and then try:

```
DBaseSheet.UsedRange.Copy Sheet5.Range("A1")
```

Comment: tried DisplayName's solution it worked until last night, but broke this morning. So, I tried your solution and it sill caused a new error with the copy method.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply go:

```
Sub Import()   
    Sheet5.UsedRange.Clear
    With Workbooks.Open("http://collaboration.pwc.ca/team/Plant5EngineLines/Documents/Plant 5 master build plan/Database.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False) 'open and reference your Database workbook
        .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Sheet5.Range("A1") ' copy referenced workbook sheet 1 content and paste it to sheet 5
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this. It worked in the beginning and it stopped working. Gave me the an error with the copy method.

Comment: what error and which line is throwing it? BTW: If one solution works one day and doesn't the day after, then it's related to the data variability which however you didn't give any clue about. So it's quite unfair you retired the solution mark. But that's it and suit yourself

Comment: I have updated the question. this time the error is "Copy method of Range class failed". and it is at at the line where we copy and paste at destination (4th line). also, lots of cells come up as #REF. Also, do you have any idea what could be wrong with the data? I am sorry, I am new.

Comment: as already commented, this must have to do with your data "face". so update your question with example of data to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I am with Bruce Wayne on this one

As you have opened a new workbook the focus is now on that workbook.

If you are trying to clear the cells in the workbook the code resides in (destination) after you have launched a new workbook and switched the focus you will need to reference the original workbook to do so, like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Cells.Clear
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I tried DisplayName's solution and it worked until yesterday. then it stopped working. it gave me the same error. So I added your solution to his code, tried Gary's Student's solution, Even Gary's Student's solution with your comment. it caused the same error.

Comment: Does it not work if you try your original code but change just that one line?

Comment: You will have to amend the paste special line also.

Comment: Sorry, I read wrong, this time the error was with the copy method of range class. I have updated my question.

Comment: I see, personally I don’t use UsedRange as it causes me more problems than it solves. I like to use the good old fashioned methods for selecting my data. Merged cells are the enemy of VBA.

Comment: I used the range method of selecting the data. caused the same error. also, I noticed that lots of values say #REF. and it's not pasting in the sheet 5 but sheet 6.